# How to know when the user has completed the inputting the elements in angular forms

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I'm using angular reactive forms to build a form for the array of nested objects. I'm able to plot the form and it is working as expected, but in one scenario I want to able to populate a certain input box with the values that is entered in the UI currently

**What I want?**
Below is my UI as you can see I have an array of properties. What I want is when ever user enters an propertyName. I want to be able to add that as an array and display a dropdown for the messageId field (it is a multi select kendo component)

[image]

**What I have?**

To listen to the propertyName change I have used the Observable that angular forms already provides for each FormControl and wrote the below code

```
 var propertyNameControl: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

    propertyNameControl.valueChanges.forEach(
      (value: string) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.propertyList.push(value)
      }
    );
```

But valueChanges event getting triggered for every single keypress instead of onblur. So if the user enters Apple as the property name.I will have **(A, AP, APP...)** in my list.
[image]

**Question**
How can I subscribe to onblur event of input box of the FormControl? Basically i'm looking for something like **propertyNameControl.onFocusOut.forEach()**

Comment: `onblur` event is nothing but the `touched` event , it is fired when the control is blurred.

Comment: Yes @RahulSingh. I want my FormControl to hook into that event

Comment: @gunter gave the answer thats worth looking into

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can set an option for controls to update on `blur` instead of on `change`:

```
const control = new FormControl('', {validators: Validators.required, updateOn: 'blur'});
```

or for template-driven forms

```
<form [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

or for individual input elements

```
<input [(ngModel)]="firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

I just saw, this seems to be Angular 5 only (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta4-2017-08-16, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta3-2017-08-09)

Comment: I wish we had something like that in angular 4 :(

Comment: I see. Perhaps you can live with some workaround until you are able to migrate to Angular 5.